# How to pass a Javascript function as an argument in Javascript Interface?

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-jsinterface

How to pass a function as a parameter in Javascript Interface, save it as a string and then call?

For example, I describe the `Javascript Interface`:

```
class JSInterface{
  String myFunction;

  //set function into myFunction attribute
  @JavascriptInterface
  public void setMyFunction(String func) {
    this.myFunction = func;
  }

  @JavascriptInterface
  public void executeMyFunction() {
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+this.myFunction);
  }

}
```

Add it:

```
//...

webview..addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface, "application");

//...
```

In `JS`:

```
window.application.setMyFunction(function(){
        //some code here...
});
```

**NOTE:** Transfer function from `JS` need in this form, not as a string or json.

But in fact, in `setMyFunction` i get `"undefined"` but expect `"window.application.setMyFunction(function(){ //some code here...});"`. Tell me please what to do, I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, when function passed as null, we need to declare the function that will be send the js function into `JS Interface` as string.

We also need to do this  when `onPageFinished`.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript: window.APPLICATION.setMyFunction = function(func){"
        + "window.APPLICATION.setMyFunctionAsString(func.toString());"
        + "};");
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
}
```

...and `setMyFunctionAsString` in `JS Interface`:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void setMyFunctionAsString(String func) {
    this.myFunction = func;
}
```

Now, finnaly, when we do:

```
window.APPLICATION.setMyFunction(function(){
        //some code here...
});
```

we will have `"window.APPLICATION.setMyFunction(function(){\n//some code here...\n});"` in `myFunction` and can easily call it like:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void executeMyFunction() {
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+this.myFunction);
}
```

I hope that this will help someone =)

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

[Convert Javascript Object (incl. functions) to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264916/convert-javascript-object-incl-functions-to-string)

then attach function call to the string:

```
function(){
..
}()
```

and call `eval()` on that string.

Comment: Do not quite understand what you mean. The problem is that I can not do anything on the `Javascript side`. I can only handle parameters that are passed to `Javasctipt Intarface`.

Comment: What executes the javascript then? If this is handled on client side, the the function in string should be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, i need to set string like 
`"function(){
        //some code here...
}"` into `myFunction` attribute. It will be enough. But i get only `"undefined"`.

Comment: Yes, I read it, but, as I said, I can not do anything on the Javascript side, only on the Java side.

Comment: Something on client side needs to execute the statement I suppose, anyway if you want self invoking function, add '()' at the end.